# Community Plus User - Contact sharing via SOQL does not match List View

Tags: visualforce, soql, permissions, community-cloud, with-sharing

In my `Visualforce Page`, I just use the following code to get a name list of contacts that the current user can visit.

```
public with sharing class TestClass{
    public String getAllContactNames(){
        Contact[] contacts = [SELECT Name FROM Contact];
        String[] res = new List<String>();
        res.add(String.valueOf(count.size()));
        for(Contact c : contacts){
         res.add(c.Name);             
        }
     return String.join(res, '\r\n');
    }
}
```

The Markup for the VF page is like the following:

```
<apex:page controller="TestClass">
  <h1>List All Contacts</h1>
     <pre>
        {!AllContactNames}
     </pre>
</apex:page>
```

It works well with different user with different profiles, and each user can see the possible contacts that he has permission.
But when I log-in with a customer community plus user, I can see only several records in this list. Then I tried to visit the standard List View for "All Contacts"(of course with the Customer Community Plus User), I can see more contacts.

We tried with several experiments and we can realize the following:

- This issue will only occur when the sharing setting of contact be
  default "Controlled by Parent"
- We should not user "without sharing",because that will let user see all contacts, and if a contact is not link to any account, it is private, the user without View All permission should not see it. (See:https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gkohAAA)
- It seems like that when we use "with sharing" in apex code, only the contact that links to the same account with the current user, and the contact owned by this user will be returned.
- Till now, we only notice the strange behavior with a customer community plus user, for a standard user profile, this issue never occur.

So we are confused now, and we have the following questions:
What we should do to get the the same result with the standard list view returned?
Or actually the apex code "with sharing" did the correct behavior?

Comment: See [Contact Sharing Rules do not grant users access to Contacts as expected](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000004005&language=en_US&type=1). Do these users have access to the parent accounts?

Comment: I think you should narrow down the problem to a specific record. May be take one contact, which you see in the standard list view but not in your query and then compare that contact with another one which is displaying in the list view and your query. Also check this question http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/153705/contactaccesslevel-is-read-on-accountshare-object-but-user-cannot-access-the-c

Comment: @javanoob I have already compared the difference. Actually I can access both the contact that does or does not included in the returned value by my code. So I think actually the Community Cloud have permission to access the record that listed in the standard list view. But, why "with sharing" Apex code return limited result? I don't understand. This issue never occurs in a standard salesforce user. Does it because of there is strange result with Community Cloud User?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Thanks for your answer, actually when I try to read all accounts with this user, all Account records can be reached, because the default sharing rule for Account and Contract is Public Read/Write.

Comment: The community might have an easier time assessing this behavior if you share your markup as well.

Comment: To make the question more clear, I change the Community Cloud User to "Customer Community Plus User", which can be found in the profile name of Salesforce.

Comment: It is become more interesting now... Just now I try to use the standard list view controller to show all contacts, as the following topic [Using List Views with Standard List Controllers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_sosc_list_views.htm), when I access this page with a Customer Community Plus user, I can see the same result as "with sharing" apex code returned, but not the same as the "All Contacts" list view returned. So, does the Contacts tab does not use the standard list view controller to fetch data?

Comment: I saw another guy meet similar issue with the customer community plus user:[Customer community plus users can see contacts in list views, but not the actual records](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/69444/customer-community-plus-users-can-see-contacts-in-list-views-but-not-the-actual), does it mean, the implementation of the list view in the contacts tab have some problem on the sharing model?

Comment: @AdrianLarson, I shared all of my Apex code, as well as the VF page markups. Also, you many noticed more information in my comments. What's your feeling?